# sufficient permissions to access this page

Tags: permissions

I recently changed my DB password as security measure after having discontinued services of a coder I had worked with.  I updated my wp-config file so everything is working fine except the page(s) the coder created in my admin panel.  The pages do not show in the menu, but since I knew the url, I browsed to it and it is giving me "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page."
Any idea how to correct this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can we see the code? There isn't enough information to figure out what's going on here

Comment: Hey Tom, I wasn't sure which or what code do I need to place here.  I can see all other menu items in the admin, but when I browse to this particular item which ironically doesn't show in the menu anymore, it displays that message.  Any kind of guidance for me to look for to solve this will greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Without seeing the code, it's **impossible** to answer this question